# .NET Core - Class configured in the container with AddSingleton() needs to be a Singleton?

Tags: .net-core, singleton, .net-standard

A .NET Core Web API application consumes a .NET Standard DLL. The DLL has a Foo class that depends on the Bar class:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar bar;

    public Foo (IBar bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Bar is not a Singleton (it does not have a private constructor or .GetInstance()), but it must have only one instance shared by the entire application:

```
class Bar: IBar
{
    public int Counter {get; set;}
}
```

For this, the Web API container is configured as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton <IBar, Bar>();
}
```

Now a .NET Framework 4.6.1 Web Application also needs to consume this DLL. This application does not have a container configuration. Here are the questions:

1. When instantiating the Foo class, how to ensure that the injected Bar class behaves like Singleton? Should the Bar class have been implemented as Singleton from the start?
2. Class injected via AddSingleton() needs to be a Singleton?
3. Would the configuration of the Bar class in the Web API container, if it were a Singleton, be as shown below?

   public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
   {
   services.AddSingleton <IBar, Bar.GetInstance()>();
   }

Comment: welcome @Yuri. would implementing DI, like that used in the Core project, be a solution?

Comment: Thank you @ShaiCohen! It could be, but the point is to know if it was not possible to configure an IoC container, what would be the solution?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't being clear. you can use the _exact same DI container_. the DI container used in Core projects is available for .NET Framework 4.6.1.  `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is included in new Core projects, but can be added as a nuget pkg to existing projects, including those targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.  let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But, the question is: what about if was not possible or not desirable to configure a IoC container on the Web Application?